# how to open a second UIPopOverController over first popover button click

Tags: ipad, uipopovercontroller

Is it possible to open another uipopovercontroller from the first popover UIButton click? If yes then how can i do it?

right now i am using the given code to open a popover from UIBarButtonItem

```
optionsViewController = [[OptionsViewController alloc] init];

popOverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:optionsViewController];

popOverController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(250, 300);
[popOverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:bbiOpenPopOver permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can open a second popover from any control in a popover; the mechanism is exactly the same as opening the first one. You need a reference to the content view controller, you create a new UIPopoverController using `[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:content];`, you set whatever properties you want and then you present it.

To present it from a UIButton or other control that isn't a UIBarButtonItem use

```
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:[control bounds] inView:control permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Comment: thanks phil! But in my application i am opening an UIPopoverController that has a tableView to show the list of array. But now i want to open another UIPopoverController on the click of table cell view. I also tried the code that you have given but it adds the view on table cell.

Comment: You are working with the wrong control object if that is happening.

Comment: That's a new question; use the big Ask Question button in the top-right